# Where can I get the hash for 12.04  ISO?

Tags: 12.04, md5sum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to find the md5sums of Ubuntu ISO images?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9417/where-to-find-the-md5sums-of-ubuntu-iso-images)

I've downloaded the 12.04 LTS ISO file but I can't locate the hash file anywhere.